# Python's Theano attribute error/circular import partially initialized module problem in VS Code

Tags: python, module, package, theano

I have been trying to get Theano working on visual studio code without any success. After a whole day of fixing the issue, the most recent one is as shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\GPU NN\testing.py", line 26, in <module>
    testTheano()
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\GPU NN\testing.py", line 2, in testTheano
    from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\GPU NN\theano.py", line 4, in <module>
    theano.versionpip
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'theano' has no attribute 'versionpip' (most likely due to a circular import)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.225 seconds
```

Edit 1:
Now the error is showing this

```
from theano import tensor
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from partially initialized module 'theano' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have read a similar problem where the solution is to delete theano everywhere and reinstall it with anaconda, maybe it's because of a faulty theano installation or that I have multiple theano installed in my laptop. I have tried pip uninstall in all cmd, vscode terminal, and anaconda. I have also tried installing theano one by one using all three pip install methods and tested it with a theano code without any success. The theano code:

```
def testTheano():
    from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
    import theano.tensor as T
    import numpy
    import time
    print("Testing Theano library...")
    vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
    iters = 1000

    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
    x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
    f = function([], T.exp(x))
    print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(iters):
        r = f()
    t1 = time.time()
    print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
    print("Result is %s" % (r,))
    if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
        print('Used the cpu')
    else:
        print('Used the gpu')
# Perform check:

testTheano()
```

I'm desperate for help. Any ideas?

Comment: Using Tensorflow instead of Theano now, much easier to install and get it to run.